# Emacs on windows: using C-M

Tags: emacs

I would like to navigate in the parenthesis structure and I found this page for doing this: [navigate parentesis](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Moving-by-Parens.html).

I tried to use C-M-n (and the others) but my emacs does not recognize the combination C-M (ctrl+meta). Can someone help me?
Window 8.1 / GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601)
Thanks!

Comment: Works for me in Windows 7 Prof. Servicepack 1. Please, try to start emacs with the command line option -Q (start emacs with a minimum of customization, no startup-init files) to make sure that the problem is not caused by any customization.

Comment: Tell us what command Emacs tells you `C-M-n` is bound to.  Use `C-h k C-M-n` to find out.

Comment: @Drew Thanks for this commands. I learned something knew. My problem got obsolete. I realised that I have to push all three buttoms C-M-n together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter the sequence <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>ctrl-N</kbd>; <kbd>Esc</kbd> is a synonym for Meta (by default).

Comment: Thanks. Also with ESC it does not work. I got the M- but it does not accept Ctrl.

Comment: My problem got obsolete. I realised that I have to push all three buttoms C-M-n together.